# Access devices in another machine

Tags: c, linux, windows, serial-port

I wish to access a device connected on a windows machine in a linux machine; these are not vm's. The device in windows can be accessed on its com port; it's running on COM9. What's the best way to do this? On the linux side, I'll write a user space application in c that will control the device connected on the windows machine. The two machines (linux, windows) are connected via a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.javiervalcarce.eu/wiki/Access_to_serial_port_from_Internet on the windows machine maps the com port to a tcp port.    Then it's just socket programming on the linux side.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous [COM port redirector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector) solutions available, on Windows, Linux, etc.

Some support transporting of hardware handshaking lines (DTR, DCD etc) conforming to [RFC 2217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217).